# Merge data frames keeping a multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`. One has a multi-index, say `['A', 'B']` and the other has a single index `['B']`. I would like to merge data from `df2` into `df1` via the index `'B'` while preserving my multi-index `['A', 'B']`. How would I go about this?

See the example below

```
data = {
    'state': ['California', 'New York', 'Texas'],
    'capital': ['Sacramento', 'Albany', 'Austin'],
}
df_state = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index('state')

data = {
    'state': ['California', 'California', 'New York', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Texas'],
    'year': [2000, 2010, 2000, 2010, 2000, 2010],
    'population': [33871648, 37253956, 18976457, 19378102, 20851820, 25145561],
}
df_state_year = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index(['state', 'year'])

df_state_year.merge(df_state['capital'], on=['state'], how='left')
```

the result is a dataframe with a single index 'state'. I would like to retain the original multi index ['state', 'year'].

Using the answer by Scott Boston I ended up with

```
df_state_year.reset_index()\
             .merge(df_state['capital'], on=['state'], how='left')\
             .set_index(['state', 'year'])
```

It might be a version difference but merging seems to completely remove my indices. So only resetting year makes the state index dissapear. The reason I removed append is that I do not want the extra auto numbering field to be part of my index.

Comment: Can you create or add a couple of small sample dataframes and expected outputs?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I might do it this way:

```
df_state_year['capital'] = df_state_year.index.get_level_values(0).map(df_state.squeeze())
```

Output:

```
                 population     capital
state      year                        
California 2000    33871648  Sacramento
           2010    37253956  Sacramento
New York   2000    18976457      Albany
           2010    19378102      Albany
Texas      2000    20851820      Austin
           2010    25145561      Austin
```

---

Or

```
df_state_year.reset_index(level=1)\
             .merge(df_state['capital'], on=['state'], how='left')\
             .set_index('year', append=True)
```

Output:

```
                 population     capital
state      year                        
California 2000    33871648  Sacramento
           2010    37253956  Sacramento
New York   2000    18976457      Albany
           2010    19378102      Albany
Texas      2000    20851820      Austin
           2010    25145561      Austin
```

---

Or

```
df_state.align(df_state_year, axis=0)[0].join(df_state_year)
```

Output:

```
                    capital  population
state      year                        
California 2000  Sacramento    33871648
           2010  Sacramento    37253956
New York   2000      Albany    18976457
           2010      Albany    19378102
Texas      2000      Austin    20851820
           2010      Austin    25145561
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it seems that `'year'` in your function `set_index` makes the column `year` disappear from the merge.

Try this instead :

```
df_state_year = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index(['state'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi according to your query, keeping some points in mind like readability, further implementation etc, then I would do like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

outer_index=['California','California','New York','New York', 'Texas','Texas']

inner_index=[2000, 2010, 2000, 2010, 2000, 2010]

capital=['Sacramento', 'Sacramento','Albany','Albany', 'Austin','Austin']

population_data = {
    'population': [33871648, 37253956, 18976457, 19378102, 20851820, 25145561],
}

index_hierarchy=list(zip(outer,inner,capital))
index_hierarchy=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_hierarchy)


records = pd.DataFrame(population_data,index=index_hierarchy)

records.index.names=['State','Year','Captial']

records
```

**Output**

[image]

Note: You can go with above approach if you are manually creating data like (state,capital,population).